# Popup html not loading

Tags: html

I want to embed the following code which is supposed to generate a "Book a call" button where after clicking a calendly popup should appear.

The button appears but when I click on the button, the calendly does not load.

Any idea what is wrong?

```css
.calendly-widget {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Calendly link widget begin -->
<link href=" https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src=" https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js" type="text/javascript" async></script><a href="" class="calendly-widget" onclick="Calendly.initPopupWidget({url:" https://calendly.com/simpla-worfklows-hannahm/30min "});return false;">Book a call</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using single quotes (`'`) within the `onclick` handler attribute, like this:

```
<a href="" class="calendly-widget" 
    onclick="Calendly.initPopupWidget({url: 'https://calendly.com/simpla-worfklows-hannahm/30min'}); return false;"
```

```css
.calendly-widget {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Calendly link widget begin -->
<link href=" https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src=" https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js" type="text/javascript" async></script><a href="" class="calendly-widget" onclick="Calendly.initPopupWidget({url: 'https://calendly.com/simpla-worfklows-hannahm/30min'});return false;">Book a call</a>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for getting back to me quickly! It works :D